# How to get intermediate data between the layers in TensorFlow or keras?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I want to look intermediate data between layers.
How can I get intermediate output data between the layers?

Comment: It is helpful to understand what model are you asking about, to see some code that you tried and did not work for you.

Comment: You can do `sess.run("someintermediateopname")`. You can see all intermediate op names in `tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the output of the intermediate layer using tf.keras Models,

`model.get_layer(layer_name).outputs` or `model.layer[layer_index].output`

And also, you can access the activations of `intermediate layers ("nodes" in the graph)` and reuse them elsewhere -- which is very useful for something like feature extraction.

```
import tensorflow as tf
vgg19 = tf.keras.applications.VGG19()
features_list = [layer.output for layer in vgg19.layers]
feat_extraction_model = keras.Model(inputs=vgg19.input, outputs=features_list)

img = np.random.random((1, 224, 224, 3)).astype("float32")
extracted_features = feat_extraction_model(img)
```